# 500 SSL negotiation failed with perl

Tags: perl, ssl, soaplite

I am trying to connect to webservice server with perl script from the client machine SunOS 5.10 without success.

I'm using ActivePerl 5.8.8, with some other installed librairies.
I have also installed libssl0_9_8 with cacertificates dependencie.

Note the team in charge of webservice from server side said me that no certificates are managed from their side.

I have read lot of forums but I have no clear answer about this problem.
I use the following in my script :

```
use SOAP::Lite;
use SOAP::Lite +trace => 'all';
$ENV{HTTPS_DEBUG} = 1;
my $server = $conf->param("Server");
my $url = "https://$server:443/services";
my $service = SOAP::Lite->proxy("$url/service") or die $logger->error("Error: WebService $!");
```

When I launch my script, it produces the following :

```
bash-3.2# ./GetTest.pl 
SOAP::Transport::new: ()
SOAP::Serializer::new: ()
SOAP::Deserializer::new: ()
SOAP::Parser::new: ()
SOAP::Lite::new: ()
SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Client::new: ()
SOAP::Data::new: ()
SOAP::Data::new: ()
SOAP::Data::new: ()
SOAP::Data::new: ()
SOAP::Data::new: ()
SOAP::Data::new: ()
SOAP::Data::new: ()
SOAP::Data::new: ()
SOAP::Lite::call: ()
SOAP::Serializer::envelope: ()
SOAP::Serializer::envelope: getInterface SOAP::Data=HASH(0x1003e0c) SOAP::Data=HASH(0x1003b18) SOAP::Data=HASH(0x1003bd8) SOAP::Data=HASH(0x1003ce0)
SOAP::Data::new: ()
SOAP::Data::new: ()
SOAP::Data::new: ()
SOAP::Data::new: ()
SOAP::Data::new: ()
SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Client::send_receive: HTTP::Request=HASH(0x100368c)
SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Client::send_receive: POST https://<SERVER>:443/axis2/services/Service HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/xml
Accept: multipart/*
Accept: application/soap
Content-Length: 875
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://...#getInterface"
...
SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
SSL_connect:SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
SSL3 alert read:fatal:handshake failure
SSL_connect:error in SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write client hello A
SSL3 alert write:fatal:handshake failure
SSL_connect:error in SSLv3 read server hello A
SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
SSL_connect:SSLv2 write client hello A
SSL_connect:failed in SSLv2 read server hello A
SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Client::send_receive: HTTP::Response=HASH(0x77c3e8)
SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Client::send_receive: 500 SSL negotiation failed:
Content-Type: text/plain
Client-Date: Mon, 09 Mar 2015 10:27:04 GMT
Client-Warning: Internal response

500 SSL negotiation failed:
SOAP::Deserializer::deserialize: ()
SOAP::Parser::decode: ()
SOAP::Data::DESTROY: ()
SOAP::Data::DESTROY: ()
SOAP::Data::DESTROY: ()
SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Client::DESTROY: ()
SOAP::Data::DESTROY: ()
SOAP::Data::DESTROY: ()
SOAP::Data::DESTROY: ()
SOAP::Data::DESTROY: ()
SOAP::Data::DESTROY: ()
SOAP::Data::DESTROY: ()
SOAP::Data::DESTROY: ()
SOAP::Data::DESTROY: ()
SOAP::Transport::DESTROY: ()
SOAP::Serializer::DESTROY: ()
SOAP::Data::DESTROY: ()
SOAP::Data::DESTROY: ()
SOAP::Deserializer::DESTROY: ()
SOAP::Parser::DESTROY: ()
SOAP::Lite::DESTROY: ()
```

Note that some outputs have been hidden.

I'll be happy to provide you more information if you need to help me for resolution.

**EDIT :**

I have tested with openssl utility the connection to server and it seems work :

```
bash-3.2# openssl s_client -connect <server>:443 -tls1
CONNECTED(00000004)
depth=1 /C=FR/ST=Alpes-Maritimes/...
verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
...
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIICcjCCAds...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
...
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 1886 bytes and written 260 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ...
Server public key is 1024 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : ...
    Verify return code: 19 (self signed certificate in certificate chain)
---
```

We can see that I have to use TLSv1/SSLv3 to make it work.
Note that I have tested this command with lower version and it doesn't work.

What can I do ? 
Upgrade ActivePerl to 5.20 to take into account new specific librairies with supported TLSv1 ?
Or others ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: There are SSL handshake problems. Call the code with 'perl -MIO::Socket::SSL=debug4 ...' to get more details about the SSL handshake. Apart from that both your perl and the openssl version are fairly old and especially the latter might be the source of the problems.

Comment: Activestate specifically don't support/update modules for older (free) versions of ActivePerl. Updating to 5.20 is a good idea.

Comment: It looks like it uses Crypt::SSLeay not IO::Socket::SSL because it is such an old version. In this case the tip with debugging will not help.  Since SSLv23, SSLv3 and SSLv2 handshakes fail it might be that your system is simply too old to talk to the server, i.e. that the server requires TLS1.1+ or needs a cipher not supported by your OpenSSL version or that the server needs SNI.

Comment: I take into account your advices :
- upgrade ActivePerl from 5.8.8 to 5.20.
  Do you have any links for download or be sure that 5.20 will support ?
- Upgrade the server (where located the script)
  What kinds of SunOS 5.10 librairies (including TLS1.1+ or others mentioned) will fix this problem ?
  I don't what is cipher or SNI ? could you please explain me ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Edit (UP) please see first message

Comment: Cipher describes how  authentication and encryption will be done. SNI means server name indication and is needed if you have multiple servers behind the same IP address. If the server only supports explicit TLSv1 but not SSLv23 (according to the output of Crypt::SSLeay) then you are probably ok with the version of OpenSSL, but not with the version of Crypt::SSLeay (since it does not try TLSv1 explicitly). I'm not sure what is all needed for upgrading your system, but usually you don't need ActiveState Perl on UNIX but the normal Perl version is sufficient.

Comment: But at the end probably everything will be hard on such an old system. SunOS 5.10 was released 10 years ago!