# LWP::UserAgent and 500 SSL negotiation failed

Tags: perl, ssl, openssl

I'm running an old Debian server that once a day fetches a webpage through a Perl script. Since yesterday, the script fails with a "500 SSL negotiation failed" error.

```
use strict;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $browserObj = LWP::UserAgent->new();

$response = $browserObj->get( "https://www.domain.tld" );
print $response->status_line . "\n" if( ! $response->is_success );
```

Like I said, it's an old server running old versions of everything:

- Perl: 5.8.8
- OpenSSL: 0.9.8c
- LWP: 5.805
- Crypt::SSLeay: 0.57

I made a snapshot of the server so I could try all kinds of solutions and return to the snapshot if it fails. Which is exactly what I did after each test, return to the original server state.

**Test 1:**
First thing I tried was updating OpenSSL to 1.0.2d. That did not help, I still got the "SSL negotiation failed" error. I then updated Crypt:SSLeay. That broke SSL altogether (caused the server to be unable to connect to any secure server).

**Test 2:**
Updated Crypt::SSLeay without updating OpenSSL. Caused the server to unable to connect to secure servers again.

**Test 3:**
Updated OpenSSL to 1.0.2d. Updated LWP. Made no difference. Still got "500 SSL negotiation failed"

Is there anything else I could try?

PS: For several reasons I'm unable to update Debian itself.

Comment: I would _guess_ your remote server no longer supports older versions of SSL. There's a bunch of older SSL versions that are dangerously insecure, so sites are starting to deprecate them. E.g. something like this: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/71457/how-can-i-verify-that-sslv3-protocol-is-disabled

Comment: Yes, that was my guess also.

Comment: In which case I'm not really sure how you'd test it - verify with wget maybe?

Comment: wget also gives an error on that site: (SSL handshake failed. Unable to establish SSL connection).

Comment: So, your problem isn't a perl one, it's a bit more fundamental than that.

Comment: Did your certificate expire?

Comment: I think wget fails because it's an older version as well. I don't think there's a single solution that will make both Perl and wget work. They probably both require their own solution.

Comment: Please post the exact URL you are using to connect to the server, and post the output of `openssl s_client -connect <hostname>:<port> -tls1 -servername <hostname> | openssl x509 -text -noout`. Do so by adding it to your question by clicking *Edit* (and don't post it as a comment). Otherwise, we can't reproduce it and there's not enough information to help troubleshoot it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [500 SSL negotiation failed with perl](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28940024/608639).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work for Perl. As I suspected, each program on the server that uses SSL needs to be patched seperately. But this was the solution for Perl:

**1) Update OpenSSL (to version 1.0.2d)**

This is a necessary step for every program that uses SSL! On my Debian system, I used the instructions found [here](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/openssl.html).

**2) Update Net::SSLeay**

This was necessary otherwise step 4) would fail.

```
$ cpan Net::SSLeay
```

**3) Update Getopt::Long**

Again, this step was necessary otherwise step 4) would fail.

```
$ cpan Getopt::Long
```

**4) Update Crypt::SSLeay**

Note that this will also update LWP.

```
$ cpan Crypt::SSLeay
```

Comment: In fact, updating `Crypt::SSLeay` will install `LWP::Protocol::https` which will pull in `IO::Socket::SSL` and `Net::SSLeay`. Unless specific manual steps are taken to override this, it will then cause `Crypt::SSLeay` not to be used at all, but it will have served the purpose of transitioning the user to `Net::SSLeay`.