# How to validate whether an https site is launching or not

Tags: perl, lwp-useragent

I want to check whether an https site is launching or not.
How can i find this using Perl LWP module to get the content of an https site. 
I tried LWP::UserAgent module, to get the redirected URL

```
$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->agent("$0/0.1 " . $ua->agent);
$req = HTTP::Request->new(HEAD => 'http://some.com');
$req->header('Accept' => 'text/html');
$res = $ua->request($req);
$res->is_success => This results in false. giving the below error.
```

500 SSL negotiation failed.

Note: there is redirection envolved in this.. Where the final url is an https and not http.

Can anyone guide me how to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

Did you read the [README.SSL](https://metacpan.org/source/OALDERS/libwww-perl-6.23/README.SSL) file that comes with LWP? It tells you to install [LWP::Protocol::https](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Protocol::https).

> As of libwww-perl v6.02 you need to install the LWP::Protocol::https module from its own separate distribution to enable support for https://... URLs for LWP::UserAgent.
>
> This makes it possible for that distribution to state the required dependencies as non-optional. See https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=66838 for further discussion why we ended up with this solution.

**Update:** [This answer seems relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32581367/lwpuseragent-and-500-ssl-negotiation-failed). You might need to upgrade a lot of your software.

Comment: LWP::Protocol::https package is already installed and present under lib\LWP\Protocol. but still i am getting 500 SSL negotiation failed error. I am actually new to perl, Please let me know if i need to do something more.